# Samsung s7 only asks for fingerprint scan not giving option to enter password

Tags: samsung, screen, password

My new Samsung S7 was restarted today with an android update from T-Mobile.
When it turned on, I unlocked it using a password. After few uses today, the fingerprint scan failed and each time I try again, the lock period increases and does not allow me unlock with password. I do have a password, but it does not give me an option to type it in.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem on my Galaxy S6 recently.  No matter how many attempts I made in different positions, the fingerprint reader decided, as it often does, that it simply wasn't going to accept my fingerprints.  Frustrated, I had no option but to continue trying (and failing) to scan my fingers with ever-increasing timeouts because it wasn't giving me the option to type my backup password.  With only a few attempts left before it would erase my phone, I remembered that sometimes text to the effect of "Swipe to enter password" appears at the bottom of the lock screen.  Even though this text wasn't currently visible, I tried swiping (up from the bottom, if that matters) and a password prompt finally appeared.

TLDR - The problem: finicky fingerprint reader meets poor UI.  The solution: swipe on the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well I waited long enough and it finally gave me the password screen.